# DateTime condition in where clause doesnt work correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, where-clause

I have row in my table with first column datetime type:

```
2021-11-01 08:51:56.123 102 296
```

When I use the select commands below, I get same result (this row):

```
select * from  cmd where timestamp = convert(datetime, '2021-11-01 08:51:56.122')
select * from  cmd where timestamp = convert(datetime, '2021-11-01 08:51:56.123')
select * from  cmd where timestamp = convert(datetime, '2021-11-01 08:51:56.124')
```

I request that only the second command picks this line.

How to do it?

SQL Server is version 14

Comment: `datetime` isn't that precise. You should use `datetime2` if you really-really want such precision. What are you trying to do though? Why do you want microsecond precision? You can't ensure the timestamp is unique no matter the precision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DATETIME` has a precision of (about) .003 seconds. This means it can represent only every 3rd thousands of a second and everything else is *rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds, as shown in the following table.*

```
User-specified value    System stored value
01/01/98 23:59:59.999   1998-01-02 00:00:00.000
01/01/98 23:59:59.995

01/01/98 23:59:59.996

01/01/98 23:59:59.997

01/01/98 23:59:59.998   1998-01-01 23:59:59.997
01/01/98 23:59:59.992

01/01/98 23:59:59.993

01/01/98 23:59:59.994   1998-01-01 23:59:59.993
01/01/98 23:59:59.990

01/01/98 23:59:59.991   1998-01-01 23:59:59.990
```

You can use `DATETIME2(3)` instead of `DATETIME` for more precision.

For more details, please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: It looks  you right. I tried to use datetime as a unique identifier of the record to update from PLC, because PLC doesn't have bigint (8 bytes) only int (4 bytes), but I guess I have to use int as PK and reset it after some time. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @jakkar You have several other options to identify records in a database, almost all of them can also be represented as a string or number and are supported by lots of other languages. You can take a look at `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` for example, which can easily be converted to a binary or string value in SQL Server which then can be used in any other system.